# How to use jquery index in a ul that include divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using my code I get `-1` ... I should get 2 instead.

I need to get the position of an `li` with class `focus` within `ul` without considering the div tags like `<div class="clm-XXXX">`

How should  I change my code?
Please note (I cannot change the HTML structure).

http://jsfiddle.net/4bJtr/3/

```
   <div class="snippet-content">
<ul class="layout-1">
    <div class="clm-1">
        <li>content 1</li>
    </div>
    <div class="clm-1">
        <li>content 2</li>
        <li class="focus">content 3</li>
        <li>content 4</li>
        <li>content 5</li>
    </div>
    <div class="clm-3">
        <li>content 6</li>
        <li>content 7</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't wrap the li elements in divs... that's not proper HTML

Comment: `li` under `div`? bad html.

Comment: I not Richard but I must live with it as it comes from a CMS with legacy code

Comment: Yikes!  Working with legacy code sucks. Sorry to hear that.

Comment: is adding a div between a ul/li even valid syntax ?

Comment: Whoever wrote the legacy code wrote totally invalid code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't good html, but here's your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7rru/

```
var result = $('.snippet-content li').index($('.focus'));
```

Your original selector (`'.snippet-content ul > li.focus'`) wasn't selecting anything to begin with, since there are no `li` elements directly under `ul` elements (even though they should be...),

Also, to use `index()`, you need to send a parameter specifying which element you want the index of. According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/), `index('.focus')` *should* work, but for some reason in this case it isn't.

Comment: +1 although it can be shortened with just `.index('.focus');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought so too, even went to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to confirm, but this isn't working for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/zcb3n/

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $('ul li.focus').index($('.focus'));

/*and index start from 0 not to 1

if you get one it means it is in 2nd position*/
```

reference [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)